# вывести число в выражении

Tags: perl

есть выражение:

```
my $z = "1 + 1 + 1";
print $z; # 3
```

как сделать что бы результатом выражения была цифра "3"

Comment: `print eval($z)`

Comment: благодарю, интуитивно понимал, что нужно двигаться в направлении eval

Answer (score 1):

Нужно запустить ваш код, который находится в переменной `$z`:

```
my $z = "1 + 1 + 1";
print eval($z)
```

Если код большой и находится в файле, то можно применить `do` или `require`, они помогут съекономить вам пару строк на открытии файла